# Getting Error in the Following Code of Implementing Frequency

Tags: java, collections

Hello EveryOne I want to Sort the text of a file according to their frequency.I am getting Error at runtime outofmemory Error.Please Give response as soon as possible.

```
import java.io.*; 

import java.util.*;

import java.util.Collections;   

class SortedInAlphaOrder

 {

public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException{

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter the filename with path : " );

          //String filename = input.next();

          File f = new File("Ashish.txt");

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

          StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

          String str =br.readLine();

          while((str!= null)){

          buffer.append(str);

          buffer.append(" ");

          }

          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(buffer.toString().toLowerCase());

          while(st.hasMoreTokens()){

                String s = st.nextToken();

                list.add(s);

                }

            HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);

            List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(set);

            Collections.sort(arrayList);

            for(Object ob : arrayList){

                    System.out.println(ob.toString());

                }

            }           }
```

Getting Error OutofMemoryHeap Error.Help me out.

Comment: How big is `Ashish.txt`?

Comment: So you create a list, from which you create a set, from which you create a list and keep, all of that in memory...

Answer (score 5):

I think I see your problem. You assign `str` to `br.readLine()` one, but your while loop only stops when `str == null`. I'm assuming that the first `br.readLine()` is returning a non-null `String`, and you keep checking if it is `null` in your while loop. As a result, your wile loop never stops and you eventually get a `OutOfMemory` error. Instead, you should change your code like this (untested).

```
// ...other code
String str;
while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
      buffer.append(str);
      buffer.append(" ");
}
// ...other code
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be doing very redundant stuff. You should be taking the words directly into a Collection and running the sort on them.

Anyways you can always execute the same program with increased memory by providing `-Xmx128M` option.